# How to override virtuemart user controller?

Tags: joomla, components, virtuemart

I have one component named com_vip(which was developed by me) and  am using virtuemart too. 
Problem is that i have to modify site/components/com_virtuemart/controller/user.php file just because of my newly created component(com_vip). But i think it is not better technique to modify core files of virtuemart. That's why i would like to override this (user.php) controller and would like to use in my component(com_vip).

How can i override this controller (com_virtuemart/user.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this post as reference: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/7630/9253

Also, according [official Joomla documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core), the right way to override the controllers, is writing the new files in template's folder:

**Using a templating method**

*Override Base Component Controller*

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/code/COMPONENT_NAME/CONTROLLER.php
```

*Override Another Component Controller*

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/code/COMPONENT_NAME/controllers/CONTROLLER_NAME.php
```

*Override Models*

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/code/COMPONENT_NAME/models/MODEL_NAME.php
```

*Override Views*

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/code/COMPONENT_NAME/views/VIEW_NAME/VIEW_NAME(.FORMAT).php
```